# Visual Studio 2019 Auto Formating {w=1;} to { w = 1; }

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting, visual-studio-2019, curly-braces

I'm doing some work in VS 2019, I know there is a section where I can change the auto formatting. I went through what I think to be the who list however it still keeps changing my {} formatting, its driving me nuts. Below I put an example of what I am talking about.

[image: Picture of problem]

Example of problem:

```
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x56)) {w=1;}else{w=0;}
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x41)) {a=1;}else{a=0;}
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x53)) {s=1;}else{s=0;}
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x44)) { d=1; } else{ d=0; } ///this one is the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem with auto formatting. You can access auto-formatting

**Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting**

There are multiple options of formatting.
Your problem can be fixed by un-checking the

> Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed
>
> Automatically format block when I type a }

Comment: Thank you. I missed that option, this helps allot!